# 8 or 17 digit only Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am a novoice in regular experssion.
I need a regex for 8 or 17 digit only validation.

its for a vehicle VIN validation. system should accept for 8 or 17 digit vin with small and camel case alphabets

Could someoone please help.....

Comment: i dint try dude.. i have not done any regex before

Comment: @PunithRaj: Then read up on them (there's no shortage of material). You want to learn to fish, not be given fish.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for educating, not a free freelance coder service. "I am a noob" is not an excuse, everything you said still reads to me as "Here's requirements, send me teh codez". Which I would expect to hear from my boss (not literally ofc).

Answer (score 11):

Just consider 8 digits and optionally 9 more digits

```
/^\d{8}(\d{9})?$/
```

Meaning is:

```
^        start of string
\d       a digit
{n}      repeat n times
(...)?   optional part
$        end of string
```

Comment: and it should allow 0-9 a-z A-Z.. can u please give for that

Comment: Explaining your regex further would be of much help. I guess a person not having worked with regexes before might still have some problems there. Giving them a solution to copy will help for the actual problem -  explaining it will help for all future problems.

Comment: its for a vehicle VIN validation. system should accept for 8 or 17 digit vin with small and camel case alphabets

Comment: @PunithRaj: instead of `\d` you can say for example `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 3):

use this regex `^((\d{8})|(\d{17}))$`

Answer (score 3):

for that you could just put two regexes together:

```
/^(\d{8}|\d{17})$/
```

When you have multiple distinct possibilities you can always do

```
/(one-regex|another-regex)/
```

Comment: I like this answer better. It also explains a generic way of doing.